# set workbook depending on the workbook that is open

Tags: vba

I have 2 workbooks that I run macros on `"Air.xlsx"` and `"Ocean.xlsx"`, they are basically the same but for different purpose. I want to check if one of them is open , and set one of them as `Wsht` . I can't set them as `set Wsht = activesheet` because the macro starts from a different sheet.

```
Set Wsht = Workbooks("Air").ActiveSheet
Set Wsht = Workbooks("Ocean").ActiveSheet
```

an error would occur on this because i would only have one of them open.

I was suggested using below method, but i don't think it's an efficient way to do it

```
For Each wb In Workbooks

    If wb.Name = "Air.xlsx" Then

    Set PASsht = Workbooks("Air").ActiveSheet


End If

Next
```

Is there a way to check if `Air` or `Ocean` sheet is open and set one as `Wsht`?

Thanks

Comment: There is only one `ActiveSheet`. A Workbook does not have a property `ActiveSheet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a sheet on whichever workbook is open.  Try the code below.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrksht As Worksheet

    If WorkbookIsOpen("Air.xslx") Then
        Set wrksht = Workbooks("Air.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ElseIf WorkbookIsOpen("Ocean.xlsx") Then
        Set wrksht = Workbooks("Ocean.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Else
        'Neither book is open, throw an error or something.
    End If


End Sub

Public Function WorkbookIsOpen(FileName As String) As Boolean

    Dim TestBk As Workbook

    'Trying to set a reference to a closed workbook will 
    'throw an error - Err.Number = 0 will return TRUE or FALSE.    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set TestBk = Workbooks(FileName)
        WorkbookIsOpen = (Err.Number = 0)
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```